# Calculating delta time

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to calculate deltaTime, but it's not correct.

What's wrong in my code?

```
//declared outside
private long timeSinceStart = System.nanoTime() / 1000;
private long oldTimeSinceStart = 0;
public static long deltaTime = 1;

while(running)
  timeSinceStart = System.nanoTime() / 1000;
  deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
  oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` returns the time in nanoseconds.

In order to get it in milliseconds, do `System.nanoTime() / 1000000`.

Here is an example how to calculate delta time properly.

```
long last_time = System.nanoTime();

while(running) {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    int delta_time = (int) ((time - last_time) / 1000000);
    last_time = time;
}
```

Comment: Your correct code is fixing MORE than your text explains.
Because the real problem with OPs original code was that he NEVER was saving the start-time (overwriting it every loop).
The actual fix isn't the /1000 or so, its NOT overwriting last_time anymore