# Frame rate independent gameplay implementation in pure Java

Tags: java, timing

I've been looking up on FPS independent movement recently, and I somewhat understand the concept. But I'm having trouble implementing it in pure Java.

Any one have any idea of how I could implement is as well as abstract it in its own class such as "Time" class?

So, I tried implementing the suggestions in my game loop. but even though i am getting steady 60 FPS, my "deltaTime" has values of around 0.6 - 0.9, but for 60 FPS it should be 0.01 !

What is going wrong here?
Should I calculate "deltaTime" at 1 or 2?

Code :

```
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = 0.0;
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;


        // 1


        deltaTime = ((now - lastTime) / 1000000d);

        lastTime = now;

        if (delta >= 1.0) {

            // 2 :
            System.out.println(deltaTime);

            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            //System.out.println(updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
            running = false;
    }
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? What have you tried & how has it not worked?

Comment: I am having trouble with calculating the delta time using pure java functions.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111741/calculating-delta-time/111742#111742

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating delta time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111741/calculating-delta-time)

Comment: @Pikalek I tried implementing the solution, but something is going wrong. please check the post for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading  [Glenn Fiedler article](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) on that topic, it's very old but useful.
At the end of the article, he shares a solid implementation of a fixed time-step, though not in java language.
If you have a problem with the syntax, please point to the part which you can't implement in Java, so we might help.

Regarding your delta time problem, try setting a value for your fixed delta time, say 0.01, then in each update loop, add the delta time (without dividing by 1000...)to a temp variable, then check if this variable is greater than or equal to your fixed delta time, if it's, run your update function, then decrease that temp variable by the delta time, this is the same implementation in the provided link.

Comment: I tried to implement the suggestions in my game loop, but i get the wrong values for delta time.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1000000000.0? and why are you using the nanoseconds instead of milliseconds inside the while loop?

Comment: Edited my answer.